# DVD DL won't boot on my computer

Tags: linux, boot, dvd, iso-image, burning

I burned to a Dual Layer DVD (about 8.5 GB) a Linux Distribution called Manjaro. Not only the OS, I put on DVD some packages with their dependencies. 
The way I burned the DVD was:
I extracted Manjaro ISO on a folder on my pc and then I copied all extracted files on DVD directory to be ready for the burning process. Then i put the packages on DVD directory. 
This was only a copy-paste workflow, i have not used any software or programs. 
I didn't burn the ISO image directly to DVD bcs i was afraid that the packages and their dependencies won't burn to DVD. 
Is it a wrong method that BIOS didn't boot and recognize Manjaro OS on DVD?
If it is, is there another way how to solve this problem, repair the DVD and make it bootable? 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you booting using UEFI or CSM aka. BIOS or legacy boot?

Comment: Using BIOS, not UEFI. I have an old HP 635 laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIOS boot relies on a [*boot sector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector). It's a sector on disk which contains boot code. It's part of the partition table or a single partition, but it's not a file. When BIOS boots, it loads code from this sector into RAM and executes it.

Your method preserves files only, but all non-filesystem data (such as boot sectors) is lost in the process. This makes disks produced with this method not bootable - they don't contain boot code in the boot sector.

The best way to solve this issue would be to boot with UEFI. It's been a standard boot method for a decade now and is supported by virtually all boot disks. UEFI boot doesn't rely on boot sectors, but uses loaders stored in the filesystem instead, so your method would work.

Alternatively, if you want to stick to legacy boot, you can use a proper tool to edit this ISO and then burn it. Extracting will break the boot sector, so you should edit the actual ISO and burn the resulting file. I've been using [MagicISO](http://magiciso.com/) to do this years ago. By now it's probably massively outdated, but you can take a look just to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can upvote and/or accept it as a solution. This will mark the question as solved (making it easier to find for others with the same problem) and give me some reputation points.